# How can I swap two lines using sed?

Tags: linux, sed

Does anyone know how to replace `line a` with `line b` and `line b` with `line a` in a text file using the sed editor?

I can see how to replace a line in the pattern space with a line that is in the hold space (i.e., `/^Paco/x` or `/^Paco/g`), but what if I want to take the line starting with `Paco` and replace it with the line starting with `Vinh`, and also take the line starting with `Vinh` and replace it with the line starting with `Paco`?

Let's assume for starters that there is one line with `Paco` and one line with `Vinh`, and that the line `Paco` occurs before the line `Vinh`. Then we can move to the general case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sed -f
/^Paco/ {
:notdone
  N
  s/^\(Paco[^\n]*\)\(\n\([^\n]*\n\)*\)\(Vinh[^\n]*\)$/\4\2\1/
  t
  bnotdone
}
```

After matching /^Paco/ we read into the pattern buffer until s// succeeds (or EOF: the pattern buffer will be printed unchanged). Then we start over searching for /^Paco/.

Comment: Can you break this down?

Comment: Well, you will need a basic understanding of sed's operation.. Other than that, `N` appends the current line to the pattern space, `s` tries to swap the lines, `t` jumps out of the loop, when `s` was successful, and `b` jumps back to `:notdone`.

Answer (score 4):

```
cat input | tr '\n' 'ç' | sed 's/\(ç__firstline__\)\(ç__secondline__\)/\2\1/g' | tr 'ç' '\n' > output
```

Replace `__firstline__` and `__secondline__` with your desired regexps. Be sure to substitute any instances of `.` in your regexp with `[^ç]`. If your text actually has `ç` in it, substitute with something else that your text doesn't have.

Answer (score 2):

try this awk script.

```
s1="$1"
s2="$2"
awk -vs1="$s1" -vs2="$s2" '
{ a[++d]=$0 }
$0~s1{ h=$0;ind=d}
$0~s2{
 a[ind]=$0
 for(i=1;i<d;i++ ){ print a[i]}
 print h
 delete a;d=0;
}
END{ for(i=1;i<=d;i++ ){ print a[i] } }' file
```

output

```
$ cat file
1
2
3
4
5

$ bash test.sh 2 3
1
3
2
4
5

$ bash test.sh 1 4
4
2
3
1
5
```

Use `sed` (or not at all) for only simple substitution. Anything more complicated, use a programming language

Comment: Thanks Ghostdog.  Great script. Thing is, I'm just learning sed, and this is one of the questions I need to answer (Ellie Quigley, Linux by Example).  So if anyone has a working sed example, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example from the GNU sed texinfo doc:

```
Note that on implementations other than GNU `sed' this script might
easily overflow internal buffers.

 #!/usr/bin/sed -nf

 # reverse all lines of input, i.e. first line became last, ...

 # from the second line, the buffer (which contains all previous lines)
 # is *appended* to current line, so, the order will be reversed
 1! G

 # on the last line we're done -- print everything
 $ p

 # store everything on the buffer again
 h
```

Comment: Thanks smilingthax. Your answer shows me how to reverse the lines in a file, but I'd like to just swap two lines in the file.

Comment: You can use the other commands like conditional branch (t) and labels to do that. But I'd prefer perl or something similiar for that job. Another possibility is replacing '\n' with some special character before using sed and treating everything as one long line, and in the end back-substitute the chars (e.g. with tr).

Comment: If anyone has a working example of how to do it with sed, that would be the ticket. Thanks.