# How to append or prepend a path string in a text file using sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Say I have a text file, namely, files.txt.
And in files.txt I have a list of paths, for instance:

```
/home/user/qwe
/home/user/asd
/home/user/zxc
```

I want to be able to move one line to another line, for instance:

```
/home/user/asd
/home/user/qwe
/home/user/zxc
```

I have tried to use these commands to do that. The first one works. But the second one doesn't work because of the forward slash:

```
sed -i "2d" /home/user/files.txt
sed -i "/^'/home/user/asd'/i '/home/user/qwe/'" /home/user/files.txt
```

I have tried using temporary variable with single quotes to indicate literal string but it still won't work (it is actually to be used using variable). Also I have tried using an arbitrary character to replace the forward slash because sed doesn't care in some cases but it's different this time.
How I might be able to achieve that using sed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I swap two lines using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992066/how-can-i-swap-two-lines-using-sed)

Comment: @dawg no, I don't want to swap two lines. I want the line to be replaced to go down.

Comment: are you always working with the first 2 lines in the file? or is the 'movement' based on the *content* of the lines (eg, `qwe` vs `asd`)?

Comment: @markp-fuso the 'movement' is based on the line number actually and no, i'm not only working with the first 2 lines in a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sed's pattern space and hold space:

```
sed '1{h;d}; 2{p;x}' file
```

Output:

```
/home/user/asd
/home/user/qwe
/home/user/zxc
```

See: `man sed`

Comment: Which can be `'/qwe/{h;d}; /asd/{p;x}'` to switch by pattern rather than line number.

Comment: If you want to move lines in any direction by line number, `awk` is your best bet. With `sed` you will only be able to use a line previously seen.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
sed -i 's|/home/user/asd|/home/user/qwe|g' /home/user/files.txt
```